# Graph Viewer Feature Request

Tags: arangodb

When viewing a graph, when I select an edge or node, the ID and attribute list appear at the bottom - but it would be nice to see the values of those attributes.  I can edit a node to see it's attributes , but I see no way to examine an edge attribute.

Also, short of creating a new combined attribute, can an expression be used for a a graph label such as concat(year, name)?
Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues).